# Integration of trello board with django via client side java script

Tags: javascript, django, api, trello

I am integrating existing Django project with another application(trello) via client side script.

In the template, I have a button that triggers a javascript that creates a task in trello.

However, I do not want to create this task more than one time so I am thinking what option should I choose to validate it .
1-To trigger update of the field my Django project 
2-To try to read the data from the trello application to check if the id already exists.

Both approaches should work but now I am wondering maybe there some standard approach from Django point of view for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had slow ignition . The solution is simple. If you do search for the implementation of "like" button in Django it will achieve the same goal exactly and this topic  was discussed in other questions .[Django Like Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15407985/django-like-button)